# Warning: Undefined array key; array null php/mysqli ajax, json el array llega null, y no se jecuta el succes del ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

hola tengo este problema, tengo un ajax que envía una variable(id_vaca) con el metodo POST en teoría el archivo obtener_vaca.php la obtiene hace la respetiva consulta y mediate un foreach las guarda en un array, para devolverlo en json_encode. pero al momento de hacer click el archivo obtener_vaca.php me arroja este error:
Warning:  Undefined array key "Edad" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Finca_Carrizal\obtener_vaca.php** on line **13**

**Warning**:  Undefined array key "ID_Grupo" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Finca_Carrizal\obtener_vaca.php** on line **14**
{"edad":null,"id_grupo":null}

````
$(document).on('click','.editar', function(event) {
var id_vaca = $(this).attr("id");
   $.ajax ({
     url : "obtener_vaca.php",
     method : "POST",
     data : {ID_Vaca : id_vaca},
     dataType : "json",
     success : function(data){
         console.log(data );
         $('#modalvacaedit').modal('show');
         $('#edad').val(data.edad);
         $('#id_grupo').val(data.id_grupo);
         $('#id_vaca').val(id_vaca);
         },
         }); ```
**la envía el archivo obtener_vaca.php:**-------------------------------------------------------------
``` <?php
    include "conexion.php";
    $con = conectar();

    if(isset($_POST["ID_Vaca"])){
    $ID_Vaca = $_POST["ID_Vaca"];
    $salida = array();
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Edad, ID_Grupo FROM vacas WHERE ID_Vaca ='".$ID_Vaca."'LIMIT 1");
    $stmt-> execute();
    $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
    $result = $resultSet->fetch_all();
    foreach($result as $fila){
        $salida["edad"] = $fila["Edad"];
        $salida["id_grupo"] = $fila["ID_Grupo"];
    }
    echo json_encode($salida);
}
?> ```

**el error me dice lo siguiente:**
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "Edad" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Finca_Carrizal\obtener_vaca.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "ID_Grupo" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Finca_Carrizal\obtener_vaca.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
{"edad":null,"id_grupo":null}


---

es una datatable dinámica, es decir que el atributo id_vaca lo obtengo del botón creado dinámicamente con el id_vaca, haciendo pruebas he avanzado un poco he modificado el ajax para ver si si enviava y recicbia el id_vaca, y he modificado el obtener_vaca.php de la sisguente forma a modo de prueba: lo cual me da este resultado mirnado en la red del archivo obtener_vaca.php 
{"ID_Vaca":"431","Edad":"9","ID_Grupo":"3"}
lo cual es lo que esperaba, voy a proceder a modificar el obtener_vacas.php para poder insertar en el modal

```$(document).on('click','.editar', function(event) {
                            var id_vaca = $(this).attr("id");
                            $.ajax ({
                                url : "obtener_vaca.php",
                                method : "POST",
                                data : {id_vaca : id_vaca},
                                dataType : "json",
                                success : function(data)
                                    {
                                        var json = JSON.parse(data);
                                        $('#edad').val(json.id_vaca);
                                        //console.log(data );
                                        //$('#edad').val(data.edad);
                                        //$('#id_grupo').val(data.id_vaca);
                                        //$('#id_vaca').val(id_vaca);
                                        $('#modalvacaedit').modal('show');
                        },
                    });
                        });
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?php
include "conexion.php";
    $con = conectar();
$id_vaca =$_POST['id_vaca'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vacas WHERE ID_Vaca ='$id_vaca'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo json_encode($row);
    ?>
````

Comment: Revisa la devolución de la consulta de BBDD , parece que no esta encontrado ningún registro.

Comment: ¿Y como es el elemento en HTML correspondiente a la clase `editar`?  Me gustaria ver que pones en el atributo **id** de dicho elemento, pues es el que utilizas para la consulta despues, y como ya te han dicho, esa consulta no parece devolver nada y de ahi que luego te salga el error pues parece no entrar en el foreach al no tener ningun resultado.

Comment: No uses el espacio de respuestas para dar más detalles de tu pregunta. Para ello puedes [edit] tu pregunta actual pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta.  Por otra parte, si el obtener_vaca.php te devuelve esto: `{"ID_Vaca":"431","Edad":"9","ID_Grupo":"3"}` entonces mira de cuadrar las mayúsculas/minúsculas en la recepción, más o menos así: `$('#edad').val(data.Edad); $('#id_grupo').val(data.ID_Grupo);`